# Android recyclerView problem - multi-layer scrolling content?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I am brand new in Android/kotlin development. I created my very first app with a recyclerView to display the folders and files of the phone. I put the recyclerView into a segment, created my data structure and adapter. Assembled together. It works - or seems to work. But the problem is that when I try to scroll the list, the initial state remains "ther" and the list content starts to scroll. Like it was two different layers. I have no clue where to find the problem. Never heard about such a bug like this[image: sample image]. Please give me advice, some keywords where to dig and find the solution. Thanks!

```
class BrowseFileFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var attachedCtx : Context

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        this.attachedCtx = context
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        var view : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_file, container, false)

        val modelFactory = FileBrowseModelFactory()
        val data = modelFactory.create()
        bindModelToView(data, view)

        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun bindModelToView(data: BrowseSettings, view: View)
    {
        var adapter = MyFileAdapter(data.FoldersAndFiles, this.attachedCtx)
        var recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.fileItemView)

        var linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.attachedCtx)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        var folderLabel = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.folderName)
        folderLabel.text = data.CurrentFolder
    }
}
```

The segment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BrowseFileFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folderName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fileItemView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/folderName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/folderName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folderName" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The list line layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally my adapter:

```
class MyFileAdapter(private val items: List<FileItem>, private val context: Context)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyFileAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
{
    class MyViewHolder (itemView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
        fun bindItem(f: FileItem) {
            var name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName) as TextView
            name.text = f.Name
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater
            .from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_filteitem_row, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var item = items\[position\]
        holder!!.bindItem( item )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It found out that as the whole list view is saved as a segment, this segment loads "automatically" and was loaded programatically also, and the two "loads" causes this thing. :( Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Oh "automatically" means through a nav_bar this time...